# Heroku Laravel 4.2 Mcrypt PHP extension required

Tags: heroku, laravel-4, heroku-toolbelt

I am a newbie into Heroku and I know many similar questions have been asked on stackoverflow for this but I could not find any solution that works for me.

I am getting the following issue when trying to deploy my laravel 4.2 app:

```
remote:        > php artisan clear-compiled
remote:        Mcrypt PHP extension required.
remote:        Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with error code 1
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app.
```

I tried to connect to heroku environment with `heroku run bash` command but could not get the status of mcrypt extension as no root permissions are granted to me.

Also tried to set `heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php` as buildpack. But no success.

Here is my `composer.json`

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.2.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/library",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/Lib.php",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add your `composer.json`.

Comment: @Chris,updated question with composer.json

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't specified a PHP version or a dependency on the `mcrypt` extension in your `composer.json`.

Start by depending on a particular version of PHP:

```
composer require php ~7.1.0
```

You can replace `~7.1.0` with `~7.0.0` or `~5.6.0` if you prefer.

Heroku [includes `mcrypt` by default](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#php-5-5-and-5-6) if you are using PHP 5.6. But if you're using 7.0 or 7.1 you'll [need to add it](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#using-optional-extensions):

```
composer require ext-mcrypt
```

Then update your `composer.lock` by running `composer update`. Make sure everything is still working as expected locally, then commit the updated `composer.json` and `composer.lock` files and push to Heroku again.

Note that [the `mcrypt` extension has been deprecated as of PHP 7.1](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/intro.mcrypt.php). It is probably worth considering an upgrade to Laravel 5.1 or higher which [replaces `mcrypt` with `openssl`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/releases#laravel-5.1), especially if you're working with PHP 7.1.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error while calling `composer update`. It was because the version of `php` called by `composer` was different with the version available in the `path`. setting the correct `path` to the same version of `php` solved the problem.